# Should we open another round of fact-checking on an updated version of an infographic?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

We have an existing question from 2014 - [Are American media controlled mostly by Jews?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19974/are-american-media-controlled-mostly-by-jews) - where someone has asked about the factual accuracy of an infographic that alleges that a vast majority of media executives are Jewish.

The top-voted answer is a heroic effort by @Ilya-Melamed to not only criticize the methodology of producing the table, but to individually check on dozens of biographies, and show frequent errors.

Now, another user has found an updated version of the same infographic (dated 2015, rather than 2013), and is asking basically the same question.

I am not sure whether to consider it a duplicate or not. The same methodological errors are still in place, but there are dozens of more facts to check.

Should we boldly accept the challenge of debunking every new tweak to the same claim, or do we say we've covered this one already?

Answer (score 7):

Does the new version contain any substantial new claims that aren't addressed by the existing question?

- If no, it's a duplicate.
- If yes, (for example, new columns claiming X, Y and Z media outlets are "controlled" in such a way), single them out and make the question about them. It's not a "fact check this image" or "address this broad conspiracy theory", which has been done, it's "is X specific claim true" where the image is simply proof of notability.

Answer (score 2):

My vote goes to *mark as duplicate*, it's the same claim but they are two different examples of it.

Some people clearly believe that Jews control the media -- this is the claim we should be addressing, not every single possible variation of it.

On the other hand, I am convinced that a new answer would require another heroic effort and would result in the same conclusion:

> The methodology of the supposed table is wrong.
>
> The table cherry picks its data points.
>
> The table has factual errors.